# Aapche-Camel save error information on each retry

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I have an Apache Camel route which handles messages from a queue. To better understand what is happening at runtime I also keep the execution state in a database (number of retries, last execution state,...). I would like to use the redelivery mechanism from the exception handler but which performs some processing on every failure to update my database record.

```
from("jms:myinputqueue")
    .onException(RetriableException.class)
        .maximumRedeliveries(5)
        .maximumRedeliveryDelay(10000)
        .useOriginalMessage()
        .to("log:store error information in database about each attempt") // (1)
        .end() // onException
    .to("log:apply business logic here which can throw exceptions")
;
```

The part (1) is only executed after all retries are exhausted, so only once.

I've read [Apache Camel- Message Redelivery happens before onexception block executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331244/apache-camel-message-redelivery-happens-before-onexception-block-executes) but the suggested solution ''onRedelivery'' is executed before the beginning of a new retry. I need to store the result on each failure so I can save the last state (error message) in the database.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `onExceptionOccurred` processor you can use that is called when the exception happened.

Its included in Camel 2.17 onwards: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9069

Comment: Just what I needed. Let me take this opportunity to thank you. I've integrated Camel into several projects, always with great succes. Thanks for all the effort you put in it (for so many years already) and still finding time to help people.